# Change position for bootstrap div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this script

```
<div class='col-md-6 col-left'>some text</div>
<div class='col-md-6 col-right'>some more text</div>
```

So from left site I have col-left and on right side col-right. Now, when I change width of browser to width <=400 col-left jump to top and col-right jump to bottom. Can I somehow change this? I want to have col-right on top of col-left when I have media max-width = 400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">On top on small screens, right column otherwise.</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">On bottom on small screens, left column otherwise.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: also doesn't work. If I do it, content dissapear on large screen and nothing change on mobile

Comment: ok I had to change div-s in html and now it all works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .col-right { float:left; }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't change anything

Comment: I had a typo, sorry. If it doesn't work, try !important